# how to use WebAPI by creating an instance of it like ASMX web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have Asp.NET WebApi as business layer. I want to call it's methods by simply calling business controllers.
something like this: (but i'm not able to add this webapi like a service reference)

```
Business.API.UserController Users = new Business.API.UserController();
Users.GetAllUser();
```

previously i was working with WCF web services where i was able to create an instance of web service just by adding it through "Add Service References" and setting some Endpoints.
I can't do that in WebAPI (I think). i have read so many article about it but most of them was about calling it's method by HttpRequest. 
in this way :

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())    
{    
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:38104/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();    
    HttpResponseMessage response;    
    response = await client.GetAsync("api/Weather");    
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)    
    {    
        WeatherClient[] reports = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<WeatherClient[]>();                   
     }    
}
```

I think it's a ridiculous using of an web service.
am i wrong or there is something wrong with me ?

Comment: You can use swagger (a thing to generate api description for your web service) and then use some tools that can generate client from that api description, though I admit I never did that myself.

Comment: The main problem I see in your code is that you create a new `HttpClient` for each request. That is meant to be a shared object so you don't exhaust server connections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there is nothing wrong with you, that is also not a ridiculous way of using a web service. In fact; its the *only* way to use a web service; WCF hid that code for you.

<sub>Disclaimer: There are other .NET classes and libraries that perform HTTP requests and may have a simpler API, but nothing that will hide it as a class like WCF</sub>

WCF services publish metadata about themselves, which is why "Service References" works. Web API does not have a similar concept, you have to manually do the HTTP request. You can of course wrap that code into some generic functions for reuse.

With the right helper methods, you can get close to a "RPC" interface, just needing to pass in each method's endpoint instead of a name.

Comment: Thanks. My primary problem with this approach was facing with streaming outputs and inputs. I was curious to know how i can pass an stream or get an stream using HttpRequests. so i must read fundamentals i think.

Comment: @RezaNoei At least one of the .NET Http classes has a stream API. Usually they are such a pain to deal with that its not preferred however.

Comment: So it seems that there isn't such a well defined way to go. 
Thanks again.

Comment: To return your data in a Stream instead of using memory, make return value HttpResponseMessage. In your controller class that is derived from ApiController create the return value: `responseMessage = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok)`. Create the stream: `Stream streamToReturn = ...;`; Put this stream as content in the response message: `responseMessage.Content = newStreamContent(streamToReturn); return responseMessage;

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse While useful, I believe the OP is more concerned about being a web service *consumer* than creating a new one

Answer (score 2):

It's best for classes to depend on interfaces rather than directly instantiating an `HttpClient`. I've seen applications that did this correctly with WCF services - depending on service interfaces - but then for Web APIs they throw away abstraction and directly incorporate Http requests.

Within your application you can still define an interface representing some service so that the implementation - Web API, mock, something else - is abstracted.

For example, you might depend on this interface

```
public interface IFooService
{
    FooDto GetFoo(Guid id);
    List<FooDto> GetAllFoos();
    Guid InsertFoo(FooInsertDto foo);
    void UpdateFoo(FooDto updating);
    void DeleteFoo(Guid id);
}
```

and use this implementation:

```
public class FooServiceClient : IFooService
{
    private readonly RestClient _restClient;

    public FooServiceClient(string baseUrl)
    {
        _restClient = new RestClient(baseUrl.TrimEnd('/'));
    }

    public FooDto GetFoo(Guid id)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest($"api/foo/get{id}", Method.GET);
        var foo = _restClient.Execute<FooDto>(request).Data;
        return foo;
    }

    public List<FooDto> GetAllFoos()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("api/foo/getall", Method.GET);
        var foos = _restClient.Execute<List<FooDto>>(request).Data;
        return foos;
    }

    public Guid InsertFoo(FooInsertDto foo)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("api/foo/insert", Method.POST)
            { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};
        request.AddBody(foo);
        return _restClient.Execute<Guid>(request).Data;
    }

    public void UpdateFoo(FooDto updating)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("api/foo/update", Method.POST)
        { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
        request.AddBody(updating);
        _restClient.Execute(request);
    }

    public void DeleteFoo(Guid id)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("api/foo/delete", Method.POST)
        { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
        request.AddBody(id);
        _restClient.Execute(request);
    }
}
```

This also demonstrates the use of [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). It's not recommended to create and dispose an `HttpClient` for each use. RestSharp helps manage that and provides methods to simplify sending requests and reading responses.

Comment: Thanks. i have a long journey to own this knowledges.